# Window 8 JavaScript app oncheckpoint not working

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I am porting a html5 game to win8. To save the game state, I call a function `save_game` (which uses localStorage to store some data) in `window.unload`, which of course does not work here. So I use `WinJS.Application.oncheckpoint` instead. Strangely, if I launch a game and press `alt-f4`, the game state is not saved. Debugging in VS with `console.log` in the event handler, I found that it seems to be triggered only when I resume the app. Bizarrely, if I put a break point in the code, the event handler will then be correctly executed during suspension.

Anyone has any idea why this happen? Is this a bug in win8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing known behavior when debugging your app with VS.  When you close an app via user action (Alt-F4 / top swipe), the app is actually held open for a while by the debugger.  If you set a breakpoint in oncheckpoint, debug app, press Alt-F4 and then WAIT for ~5 seconds or so, you will hit the breakpoint.  The best way to simulate a user "close" event is to use the Suspend and Shutdown option from within VS that will immediately fire oncheckpoint.

Comment: Yes when debugging I actually just used the suspend and resume options, and it appeared that console.log was only triggered after I resume the app if I didn't set the break point.